# initialize long long with value starting with 0 leads to strange values

Tags: c++

What happened here?

```
long long value;
value = 001111011112;
```

in Visualstudio debugging, the value shows with value 153358922.

If the number doesn't start with 0, all is correct...

Any recommendations how to keep using my initialization style?

Comment: do you know how to write octal literals???

Comment: ups... found what happens... octal. But still looking for a solution to keep my leading zeroes.

Comment: write them in hex

Comment: There isn't.  A leading zero is meaningless as it does not affect the value.

Comment: If you have to show `001111011112` then you'll need to store it in a string

Comment: @HansPassant `value` has a `2` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a number beginning by `0` is an octal (base 8) literal.

If you want to print this value with leading zeros, you can do:

```
long long value;
value = 1111011112;
cout << setw(12) << setfill('0') << value;
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates, they should be voted/flagged to be closed.